# How to structure git submodules

Tags: git, github

I have a project in GitHub which has 10 repos. Repo1 has no dependency. Repo2 depends on repo1, repo3 depends on repo1 and repo2. Finally repo 10 depends on repo1-9. How to make use of submodules in this case ? Are there better alternatives in this case

Comment: Are you sure you need submodules? Are the repositories you depend on being co-developed, or are they more or less static with infrequent updates? Your problem might be something that was some time ago solved using configuration management tools.

Comment: Yes correct the repositories are being co-developed.

Comment: Have you considered storing all the code from all the 10 repos in a single mono-repo? If all the code is being co-developed, this might be the simplest approach.

Comment: I have already considered putting all the code in one repo. However, it will be huge code 
 base in one repo and building one  particular service say from repo3 (which will depend on repo1 and repo2) will be an issue.  its a simplest approach however not really feasible.

Comment: Why building from a single repo should be a problem? Monorepos can handle quite a lot of content, you can use shallow clones, sparse checkouts, etc. I'm afraid that without more information I cannot really help you much.

Comment: Well .. My real problem is I have multiple services and I need to keep them in separate repos for some reasons for keeping them. Separate. When there is change in one repo, that change has to be updated on depenedency in each repo. This is a manual step and I am trying to find how can I automate this so that whenever there is a change in one repo, other repos dependency are automatically updates.